# Probability distribution type of the following variable

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm not sure to which Probability distribution type the variable "Number of previous times defaulted on loan repayment" belongs to. I was thinking of Geometric distribution. Can someone please clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain better?. Why you think is Geometric?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you know it that it is a count taking values from $0$ upwards, so it is a *discrete distribution on the non-negative integers*

Wikipedia has [lists of some named discrete distributions](http://All%20you%20know%20it%20that%20it%20is%20a%20count%20taking%20values%20from%20$0$%20upwards,%20so%20it%20is%20a%20discrete%20distribution%20%20on%20the%20non-negative%20integers) but there is no particular reason to believe it is any of these, especially as a borrower who has defaulted on loan repayment many times already

(a) is more likely to default next time and

(b) is less likely to receive a loan next time and

(c) will die or at least eventually  stop borrowing